# How to copy the word longpressed directly to clipboard in webview?

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview in my activity, when user longpressed a word a native actionbar appears with options "select all, copy, share.. etc".

At that point what i wanna do is copy the word directly to clipboard without using this native actions, and disable this native actionbar appearing.

What i achieved so on is, i can catch the word to a string copied by native "copy" action, but i wanna do it (copying job) with only longpress, thanks for helps in advance, my code :

```
final ClipboardManager cm = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    cm.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
            ClipData.Item item = cm.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0);
            try {
                String text = item.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm aware this is a deep subject and be sure that i'm workin on it for a couple of days. Anybody has an idea about answer?

Comment: anybody has no solution?